# A Case of Hyphenation

Tags: hyphens, compound-nouns

Is there a rule to explain why (in most dictionaries) words such as ***half-brother*** or ***half-sister*** are hyphenated while ***stepbrother*** or ***stepsister*** are not?

Comment: For what it's worth, Merriam-Webster and American Heritage appear to render it "half sister", which is the spelling I've personally encountered the most. Unfortunately I don't know a good answer to the larger question other than "that's just how it is."

Comment: As words evolve over time, you often see the phenomenon where noun phrases will become hyphenated words, and where hyphenated words become a single word.  English is mutable that way, and you can't predict today what general usage will be 100 years from now.  People used to spell "coordinate" as "co-ordinate" or "coördinate".

Comment: @John Feltz: I do agree with you on language(s) changing over time and this could be seen in different ways of using some words (e.g. bookshop, book shop, and book-shop). However, in the case of your example, co-ordinate, I believe using a hyphen is necessary either for easier readability or to avoid confusion (e.g. re-form NOT reform or re-creation NOT recreation).

Comment: @JohnFeltz You should post that as an answer, because it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

Compound words in English can be separated by a space (e.g. ice cream), a hyphen (your examples), or nothing (e.g. bestseller).

But, the *step* in *stepbrother*, etc. is unrelated to the English word *step* as in thing you put your foot on to move (from Wikipedia article [Stepfamily](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stepfamily):)

> The earliest recorded use of the prefix step-, in the form steop-, is
>   from an 8th-century glossary of Latin-Old English words meaning
>   "orphan". Steopsunu is given for the Latin word filiaster and
>   steopmoder for nouerca. Similar words recorded later in Old English
>   include stepbairn, stepchild and stepfather. The words are used to
>   denote a connection resulting from the remarriage of a widowed parent
>   and are related to the word ástíeped meaning bereaved, with stepbairn
>   and stepchild occasionally used simply as synonyms for orphan. Words
>   such as stepbrother, stepniece and stepparent appeared much later and
>   do not have any particular connotation of bereavement. Corresponding
>   words in other Germanic languages include: Old High German stiuf- and
>   Old Norse stjúp-.[14]

So this is not really a compound word so much as a separate word or a prefix (e.g. like *unknown*, *pregame*, etc.)

Comment: This answer is a total game-changer. Thanks for having enlightened us (not sarcastic).